# How to add a class in jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I have a DatePicker jQuery calendar in my Web App. The arrows which change to the previous or the next month are 'transparent' at the moment. However, I realised that it works beacause if I click on the "arrow" the month changes.

I've tried the following code on the Developper Tool and it works:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-next span').addClass('ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon');
$('.ui-datepicker-prev span').addClass('ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon');
```

How can I add this code sample in mi code? I've tried to include it on the "beforeShow" method but it doesn't work.

Have someone any idea to show the icons?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your icons are not being displayed properly it's probably because you are missing something like the css styles.

Anyway, answering to your question, if what you want to do is add those clases after the datepicker has opened, you can add a small delay in your `beforeShow` method like the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.ui-datepicker-next span').addClass('ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon');
  $('.ui-datepicker-prev span').addClass('ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon');
}, 500);
```

That will add the classes after 500ms which will be enough for jquery to generate the datepicker

Comment: Thank you! Actually I get it! It was a problem with the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your jquery after page load

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-next span').addClass('ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon');
    $('.ui-datepicker-prev span').addClass('ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the calendar jQuery Datepicker is inside an input. When the user clicks on the input the calendar appears. For this reason, I've tried the event "beforeShow" but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @AngelSilvan  : did you try this ?

Comment: Yes, of course. However, the only way to add the classes correctly is when the datepicker is shown. If I add the classes before (even on the afterLoad), it doesn't work.

Comment: @AngelSilvan : can you create jsfiddle for this ?